# Can The Application Icon in the Built In Search Dialog Be Clickable?

Tags: java, android

Is there anyway to capture when the user clicks on the application icon in the built in search dialog? Please note I am NOT referring to a custom dialog but to android built in search dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to make the `SearchDialog`'s app icon clickable.

But just for fun, let's assume there existed some hacky workaround that would get the job done. Cool, we have got the desired behavior... but now we have two issues:

1. The behavior of the `SearchDialog` is not consistent with other Android devices. This lessens the user experience since users expect search interfaces to work the same on all Android devices.
2. Your app now makes use of the internal APIs, which may or may not remain consistent when new SDKs are released. For all you know, the Android team could change the [**app icon's `id`**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/search_bar.xml) from `@+id/search_app_icon` to `@+id/search_home_icon`. Your hack *depends* on the internal APIs... so such a change will cause newer devices running your app to crash (as any runtime search for `search_app_icon` will return `null`).

   Further, companies like Samsung and HTC are free to alter the internal APIs before they release their new devices to the public. The next Samsung Galaxy could potentially completely re-implement the `SearchDialog` class, update its UI/theme, etc... you can never know for sure.

So basically, you can't... and you shouldn't make an attempt to do so.

---

Just because I'm bored, here's the source code that led me to my answer:

1. Check out the source code for [`SearchManager.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/SearchManager.java), and notice that the `SearchManager` keeps the `SearchDialog` as a private instance variable [`mSearchDialog`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/SearchManager.java#SearchManager.0mSearchDialog).
2. Check out the source code for [`SearchDialog.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/SearchDialog.java#SearchDialog.createContentView%28%29), and notice that the `SearchDialog` references the app icon as the private instance variable [`mAppIcon`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/SearchDialog.java#SearchDialog.0mAppIcon). Also notice that the `SearchDialog` initializes the variable through a call to `findViewById`, as seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/SearchDialog.java#SearchDialog.createContentView%28%29).
3. Check out the source code for [`search_bar.xml`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/search_bar.xml) and notice that the `ImageView` is not set to `clickable` by default. Since there are no (methods in the public SDK that alter the behavior of this `View`, there is no reliable way to make it clickable.

Comment: why could you not register a touch listener on the dialog and extrapolate if the user had clicked in the quandrant where the icon is located?

Comment: How would you know where the icon is located? How do you know that there is even an icon in the first place? How do you know how big the icon is? How do you know Samsung or HTC didn't decide to remove the `SearchDialog` all together? OK, that might be a stress... but do you know what I mean? Of course you could register a touch listener in the top left corner of the screen... but it would be near impossible to predict every possible scenario in which the icon could be displayed.

Comment: It also wouldn't work on Google TVs and a couple other devices that don't have touch screens :P

Comment: Also, on Android 3.0+ you can use the `SearchView` as an action view in the action bar... I believe that will give you the desired behavior (since the home icon in the action bar is clickable).

Comment: Unfortunately, grepcode no longer exists. I used to love that website...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's impossible to do this using the Android's public SDK.

I think the only solution is write your own custom dialog, but I'm affraid that with the built in dialog you can't accomplish this.

Comment: So registering a view touch listnener is not possible?

Comment: @jaumebd, If you are suggesting he re-write the search interface from scratch, then good luck...